# TFS 2015 stopping a build gives error

Tags: build, tfs-2015

We had upgraded our TFS from TFS 2012 to TFS 2015 and after the upgrade, whenever a build is triggered and stopped a error is thrown.

> The build has been forcefully stopped by the server because the build machine did not respond to a stop request.

This isn't a issue, but it throws a wrong impression to a second user that the server stopped responding, when the server was fine and working.
Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should go and look what's in the build agent logs for that time frame...

Comment: There was no information logged after that event. I checked the tfs admin console and there was no event present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart the build control.

If it not work, you can delete the build agent and create a new one. Try it again.

Comment: Yep tried this, now getting a different error. But I think it required a restart. I restarted the agent and controller. Thanks! For suggesting this.